# Si activo los scripts javascript, AJAX deja de funcionar

Tags: javascript, ajax

Me sucede algún conflicto u error con AJAX. Si pongo en el header un buscador mediante AJAX, y activo los script de Javascript, AJAX deja de funcionar y no me muestra ningún resultado. En cambio si desactivo los script javascript, AJAX vuelve a funcionar. ¿Qué sucede?

Buscador AJAX en el menú:

```
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" accept-charset="utf-8" method="POST">
  <!--FORMULARIO INPUT PARA BUSCAR MEDIANTE AJAX-->
  <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Buscar" aria-label="Search" name="busqueda" id="busqueda" value="" maxlength="30" autocomplete="off" onKeyUp="buscar();"/>

  <!--AQUÍ SE MUESTRAN LOS RESULTADOS DE AJAX-->
  <div id="resultadoBusqueda">   
</form>
```

buscar.php para procesar la búsqueda AJAX:

```
<?php
    //Archivo de conexión a la base de datos
    require('conexion.php');

    //Variable de búsqueda
    $consultaBusqueda = $_POST['valorBusqueda'];

    //Filtro anti-XSS
    $caracteres_malos = array("<", ">", "\"", "'", "/", "<", ">", "'", "/");
    $caracteres_buenos = array("& lt;", "& gt;", "& quot;", "& #x27;", "& #x2F;", "& #060;", "& #062;", "& #039;", "& #047;");
    $consultaBusqueda = str_replace($caracteres_malos, $caracteres_buenos, $consultaBusqueda);

    //Variable vacía (para evitar los E_NOTICE)
    $mensaje = "";

    //Comprueba si $consultaBusqueda está seteado
    if (isset($consultaBusqueda)) {

        $consulta = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM usuarios
        WHERE nombreUsuario COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci LIKE '%$consultaBusqueda%'OR apellido1Usuario COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci LIKE '%$consultaBusqueda%'OR CONCAT(nombreUsuario,' ',apellido1Usuario) COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci LIKE '%$consultaBusqueda%'");


        //Obtiene la cantidad de filas que hay en la consulta
        $filas = mysqli_num_rows($consulta);

        //Si no existe ninguna fila que sea igual a $consultaBusqueda, entonces mostramos el siguiente mensaje
        if ($filas === 0) {
            $mensaje = "<p>No hay ningún usuario con ese nombre y/o apellido</p>";
        } else {
            //Si existe alguna fila que sea igual a $consultaBusqueda, entonces mostramos el siguiente mensaje
            //echo 'Resultados para <strong>'.$consultaBusqueda.'</strong>';

            //La variable $resultado contiene el array que se genera en la consulta, así que obtenemos los datos y los mostramos en un bucle
            while($resultados = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta)) {
                $nombre = $resultados['nombreUsuario'];
                $apellido = $resultados['apellido1Usuario'];
                //Output
                $mensaje .= '
                <a href="#" value="#">
                ' . $nombre . '
                ' . $apellido . '
                </a><br>
                </div>';

            };//Fin while $resultados

        }; //Fin else $filas

    };//Fin isset $consultaBusqueda

    //Devolvemos el mensaje que tomará jQuery
    echo $mensaje;
    ?>
```

Index.php, si activo los siguiente scripts, AJAX no funciona. Si los desactivo, AJAX funciona perfecto:

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="/js/vendor/jquery-slim.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="js/vendor/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>


BUSCAR.PHP

    <?php
require('conexion.php');
$consultaBusqueda = $_POST['valorBusqueda'];
$caracteres_malos = array("<", ">", "\"", "'", "/", "<", ">", "'", "/");
$caracteres_buenos = array("& lt;", "& gt;", "& quot;", "& #x27;", "& #x2F;", "& #060;", "& #062;", "& #039;", "& #047;");
$consultaBusqueda = str_replace($caracteres_malos, $caracteres_buenos, $consultaBusqueda);
$mensaje = "";
if (isset($consultaBusqueda)) {

    $consulta = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM usuarios
    WHERE nombreUsuario COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci LIKE '%$consultaBusqueda%'OR apellido1Usuario COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci LIKE '%$consultaBusqueda%'OR CONCAT(nombreUsuario,' ',apellido1Usuario) COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci LIKE '%$consultaBusqueda%'");

    $filas = mysqli_num_rows($consulta);

    if ($filas === 0) {
        $mensaje = "<p>No hay ningún usuario con ese nombre y/o apellido</p>";
    } else {

        while($resultados = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta)) {
            $nombre = $resultados['nombreUsuario'];
            $apellido = $resultados['apellido1Usuario'];
            //Output
            $mensaje .= '
            <a href="#" value="#">
            ' . $nombre . '
            ' . $apellido . '
            </a><br>
            </div>';

        };//Fin while $resultados

    }; //Fin else $filas

};//Fin isset $consultaBusqueda

//Devolvemos el mensaje que tomará jQuery
echo $mensaje;
?>
```

Comment: ¿puedes poner todo el codigo de la pagina con problemas? Pareciera que estás teniendo problema a la hora de importar los js. Y cuando te refieres a desactivar AJAX ¿que quieres decir?. Pon tambien el codigo de la funciona buscar()

Comment: Coloca todo el código que tienes en el final de tu `body` todos los `<script>` si tienes alguno en el `head` tambien colocales para poder ayudarte.

Comment: la versión slim de jquery no incluye ajax ni efectos, habría que ver si no estás cargando dos jQuerys

Comment: Posible duplicado de [$.ajax is not a function](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/95063/ajax-is-not-a-function)

Comment: Hola! Revisa esta respuesta  te puede ser de utilidad https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/172792/22721

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tuve problemas similares a tu caso, pero necesito ver la funcion buscar que llamas, el problema es que utilizas javascript para llamar a tu ajax, y abajo estas activando otros scripts, por ejemplo, el que mas da problema es:

```
<script src="/js/vendor/jquery-slim.min.js">
```

el jquery muchas veces trae funciones activas en unas versiones y en otras no, por lo que si estas utilizando una version no compatible y llamas a una funcion por ejemplo `$('input').iCheck` que yo utilizaba, esta no era compatible con **jquery version 3**, puse otra version y si era compatible, pero me desactivaba otras funciones, asi que la opcion fue buscar otras versiones, hasta que probando utilice la version 2 y esta fue la que traia mas funciones... para hacer pruebas deberias depurar mediante la consola del navegador... pon inspeccionar elemento, consola y ahí te saldra donde encuentras el conflicto... te recomiendo **Firefox** para inspeccionar elementos.

Comment: hola jeanpitx, muchas gracias de antemano. He añadido el código de buscar.php a ver qué te parece que puede ser. ; )

Comment: saludos @r84, en realidad me referia a onKeyUp="buscar();", veo que llamas a una funcion de javascript, pero gracias por poner el php, tambien será de ayuda. por cierto queria saber si hiciste la inspeccion de elementos ??

Comment: Solucionado! En vez de poner el script: <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> he puesto el archivo: <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script> Y FUNCIONA PERFECTO! ¡Gracias!