# Uncaught TypeError: $.post is not a function

Tags: javascript, ajax

Ya importe las librerias como lei en otros problemas y sigue diciendome ese error. Alguien sabe cual podria ser el problema? Aca dejo las importaciones que uso.

```js
 if (textoBusqueda != "") {
       $.post("verifyemail.php", {valorBusqueda: textoBusqueda}, function(mensaje) {
           $("#resultadoBusqueda").html(mensaje);
       });
   } else {
       ("#resultadoBusqueda").html('<p>No se encontro nada</p>');
 };
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: voy a hacer la pregunta mas simple importas la libreria al principio del documento en el head? o despues del codigo?

Comment: Lo probe de las 2 formas y me tira lo mismo

Comment: en algun momento estas sobrescribiendo la variable intenta con `jQuery.post`

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: jQuery.post is not a function

Comment: esas adjuntandolo al principio del documento? y mas informacion de tu codigo es como muy pobre tu pregunta ya que no hay mucho con que trabajar!

Comment: Es que no hago más que eso, es un proyecto de laravel, importo desde el app la libreria de jquery y funciona por que pruebo de todo. Y me tira ese error nada mas. Lo que hago es usar un onkeypress esa funcion y me tira ese error

Comment: Revisa esta pregunta [$.ajax is not a function](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/95063/ajax-is-not-a-function)

Comment: Estas seguro que laravel lo esta pintando corrextamente que intruccion utilizas?