# mi boton de subir imagenes al servidor no responde

Tags: php, html, sql, bootstrap

cada que intento probar para subir imagenes (varias hojas que forman un capitulo),el boton no hace nada tampoco me manda a error , muestra algun mensaje en la pantalla , o me redirige a una direcion vacia.por eso es que no se que corregir para que responda.

subir_hojas.php en la carpeta bin

```
<?php 
    require_once("../bin/clases.php");
    $hoja = new Mangas();
    $hojas = $hoja->subirHojas($_POST['Capitulo'],$_POST['Volumen'],$_FILES, $_POST['mangaRel']);
?>
```

la parte del meta en el head del html relacionado a la pagina del formulario de subida

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#file").on("change", function() {
                $("#vista-previa").html('');
                var archivos = document.getElementById('file').files;
                var browser = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
                for (var i = 0; i<archivos.length;i++) {
                    var size =  archivos[i].size;
                    var type = archivos[i].type;
                    var name = archivos[i].name;
                    if(size > 5000000) {
                        $("#vista-previa").append("<h1>El archivo "+name+" supera el tamaño permitido.</h1>");
                    }else if(type != 'image/jpeg' && type != 'image/jpg' && type != 'image/png'){
                        $("#vista-previa").append("<h1>El tipo de archivo "+name+" no esta permitido.</h1>");
                    }else {
                        var objeto_url = browser.createObjectURL(archivos[i]);
                        $("#vista-previa").append("<div style='margin: 5px; display: inline';float: left;><img width='89' height='140' src="+objeto_url+" width='300' height='300'></div>");
                    }
                }
            });

            $("#btn").on("click", function () {
                var formData = new FormData($("#formulario")[0]);
                $.ajax({
                    url: "../bin/subir_hojas.php",
                    type: "post",
                    data: formData,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    success: function (r) {
                        $("#res").html(r);
                    }
                });
            });

        });

</script>
```

el formulario de subida ,aqui se encuentra el boton como id="btn" y no me salta a nada solo se ilumina por los css ,pero al clikearlo la pagina se mantiene igual no se refresca la pagina ni me redirecciona , la avista previa que le sigue funciona bien ,y los demas espacios se llenan correctamente hasta que llego ala parte del boton .

```
<?php
    $manga = new Mangas();
    $mangas = $manga->mangaUsuario();
?>              
<div class="margen ">
    <div class="container  ">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-5 jumbotron_admin ">
                <form method="post" id="formulario" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <p class="text-white">SUBIR CAPITULO </p>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="ejemplo_text_1" class="text-white">Obra</label>
                        <select  name="mangaRel" class="form-control">
                        <option value="">Seleccione un Manga</option>
                        <?php foreach($mangas as $datos): ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $datos['id']; ?>"><?php echo $datos['nombre']; ?></option>
                        <?php endforeach ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="ejemplo_text_1" class="text-white">Numero del volumen</label>
                        <input type="text" name="Volumen" class="form-control" placeholder="Numero del Volumen">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="ejemplo_text_2" class="text-white">Capitulo</label>
                        <input type="text" name="Capitulo" class="form-control" placeholder="Numero del Capitulo">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="ejemplo_archivo_1" class="text-white ">Adjuntar un archivo</label>
                        <input type="file" name="file[]" id="file" multiple>
                    </div>

                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="btn">subir Hojas</button>
                </form>
                <br>
                <div class="marco">
                    <div id="vista-previa"></div>
                    <div id="res"></div>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

la clase.php en la carpeta bin es el ultimo en la linea

```
    class Mangas extends Conexion {
        public function Mangas(){
            parent::__construct();
        }
            public function subirHojas($numeroCap,$numeroVol,$hojas,$mangaRel){//metodo con parametros del formulario
            
            if(isset($hojas["file"])){//condicional para saber si hay imagenes
                for ($i=0; $i <count($hojas['file']['name']) ; $i++) { //bucle para recorrer todas imagenes
                    $file = $hojas['file']; //array de todas la imagenes
                    $nombre = $file['name'][$i]; // nombre de la imagen
                    $tipo = $file['type'][$i]; // tipo de imagen
                    $size = $file['size'][$i]; //tamaño de la imagen
                    $ruta_temp = $file['tmp_name'][$i]; //ruta tamporales de la imagen
                    $carpeta = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/manga/img/capitulos/"; //ruta personalizada
                    if ($tipo != 'image/jpeg' && $tipo != 'image/jpg' && $tipo != 'image/png' && $tipo != 'image/png') {
                        echo $reporte .= "<p>Error: ".$nombre." no es una iamgen.</p>";//condicional para validar el tipo deimagen
                    }else if($size > 5000000){
                        echo $reporte .= "<p>El tamaño del archivo excede el maximo permitido.</p>";//condicional para validadr el tamaño deimagen
                    }else{
                        $src = $carpeta.$nombre;
                        move_uploaded_file($ruta_temp, $src);//mandamos la imagen al directorio propuesto
                        
                    }
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO capitulos(hoja, pagina, hojaRel) VALUES (:hoja, :pagina, :hojaRel)";//consulta para la insersion de registro a la base de datos
                    $statement = $this->base->prepare($sql);
                    $page = $i +1;
                    $statement->execute(array(':hoja' => $nombre,':pagina' => $page, ':hojaRel' => $mangaRel));                 
                }
                $sql = "INSERT INTO capitulosmanga(numeroCap, numeroVol, mangaRel) VALUES (:numeroCap, :numeroVol, :mangaRel)";//consulta para la insersion de registro a la base de datos
                    $statement = $this->base->prepare($sql);
                    $statement->execute(array(':numeroCap' => $numeroCap, ':numeroVol' => $numeroVol, ':mangaRel' => $mangaRel));
                echo "<p>Sus imagenes se subieron exitosamente.</p>";//respues devuelta por aJAX
            }
        }
        public function URLCapitulo($id){
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM capitulosmanga WHERE capitulosmanga.mangaRel = '$id' ORDER BY capitulosmanga.numeroCap DESC";
            $statement = $this->base->query($sql);
            $statement->execute(array());
            $resultado = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);;
            $statement->closeCursor();
            return $resultado;
        }
        public function hojas($id){
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM capitulos,capitulosmanga WHERE capitulos.hojaRel='$id' AND capitulosmanga.id = '$id'";
            $statement = $this->base->query($sql);
            $statement->execute(array());
            $resultado = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);;
            $statement->closeCursor();
            return $resultado;
        }
        public function getLink($x,$id){
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM capitulos,capitulosmanga WHERE capitulos.hojaRel='$id' AND capitulosmanga.id = '$id' LIMIT $x,1";
            $statement = $this->base->query($sql);
            $statement->execute(array());
            $resultado=$statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            return $resultado;
        }
        public function numeroFilas(){
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM capitulos";
            $statement = $this->base->query($sql);
            $statement->execute(array());
            $resultado = $statement->rowCount();
            return $resultado;
        }
        public function eliminarManga($id){
            $this->base->query("DELETE FROM manga WHERE id='$id'");
            header('location: ../_admin/panel.php');
        }
        public function eliminarCapitulos($id){
            $this->base->query("DELETE FROM manga WHERE id='$id'");
            header('location: ../_admin/panel.php');
        }
    }
```

primero va del formulario al meta.php que lo coloco  en el head del html  con require_once, para ahorrar lineas de codigo ,a todas las paginas relacionadas con la seccion de admin,luego val subir_hojas.php que tambien se encuentra en la carpeta bin y al ultimo la clase para que se suba al servidor sql .

Answer (score 1):

A simple vista no estoy seguro donde puede estar el error sin hacer pruebas, pero puedo entregar tips para debugging:

- Lo primero es revisar la consola por algún aviso de error. En Firefox es con `F12`, en Chrome con `Ctrl+Shift+I`.
- Segundo, un `console.debug(r)` en la funcion `success` para ver recibe javascript al hacer el llamado.

Con respecto al error, puede ser que el formulario se está enviando al hacer `click` (lo cual no debiese pasar si está definido como `type="button"`, pero siempre es bueno tener una función que ataja el comportamiento `submit` de formulario para que actúe de la misma forma que al hacer `click` en el botón.

```
$('#formulario').on('submit', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault()
   // la misma funcion de botón
   return false
}
```

Saludos.

Comment: le di a inspeccionar ,y al clickear el subir hojas ,salta un problema como :Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function,se refiere a esta linea del meta :`$.ajax({
                    url: "../bin/subir_hojas.php",
                    type: "post",
                    data: formData,
                    contentType: false,` en especial el ajax , debo linkear algo al meta? ,ya  tenia  esto encima :`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` pero no parece funcionar.

Comment: ya esta saolucionado :https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/95063/ajax-is-not-a-function,aqui lo dejo ,gracias .